# Firestore security rules return true for the condition of updating a field even when it is not being updated

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a collection, having documents whose f**ields are created and validated at the time of the creation of the document**. I also want to **disallow updation of values of some of the fields**. I have tried the following security rules but they have the following results:

(I don't know how but it **somehow detects those fields in the request.resource, even though they are not being updated from the android app itself**)

So, my question is am I doing something wrong in the following methods? And how should I achieve the desired functionality?

**Method 1:**

```
allow create: if request.resource.data.a == 1
              && request.resource.data.b == 2
              && request.resource.data.c == 3
              && request.resource.data.d == 4
              && request.resource.data.e == 5;
allow update: if !(request.writeFields.hasAny(['d', 'e']));
```

**Result:**

Document **Creation**: Permission **Denied** (It is surprising how create operation is being hindered by the Update security rule, as it seems)

Document **Updation**: Permission **Granted** (Updated a document created via console)

**Method 2:**

```
allow create: if request.resource.data.a == 1
              && request.resource.data.b == 2
              && request.resource.data.c == 3
              && request.resource.data.d == 4
              && request.resource.data.e == 5;
allow update: if !('d' in request.writeFields)
              && !('e' in request.writeFields);
```

**Result:**

Document **Creation**: Permission **Denied**;

Document **Updation**: Permission **Granted** (Updated a document created via console)

**Method 3:**

```
allow create: if request.resource.data.a == 1
              && request.resource.data.b == 2
              && request.resource.data.c == 3
              && request.resource.data.d == 4
              && request.resource.data.e == 5;
allow update: if !(request.resource.data.keys().hasAny(['d','e']));
```

**Result:**

Document **Creation**: Permission **Granted**

Document **Updation**: Permission **Denied**

**Method 4:**

```
allow create: if request.resource.data.a == 1
              && request.resource.data.b == 2
              && request.resource.data.c == 3
              && request.resource.data.d == 4
              && request.resource.data.e == 5;
allow update: if !('d' in request.resource.data.keys())
              && !('e' in request.resource.data.keys());
```

**Result:**

Document **Creation**: Permission **Granted**

Document **Updation**: Permission **Denied**

**Method 5:**

```
allow create: if request.resource.data.a == 1
              && request.resource.data.b == 2
              && request.resource.data.c == 3
              && request.resource.data.d == 4
              && request.resource.data.e == 5;
allow update: if !(request.resource.data.hasAny(['d','e']));
```

**Result:**

Document **Creation**: Permission **Denied** (Even here, the Create operation is being hindered by the Update Security Rule it seems)

Document **Updation**: Permission **Denied**

**Method 6:**

```
allow create: if request.resource.data.a == 1
              && request.resource.data.b == 2
              && request.resource.data.c == 3
              && request.resource.data.d == 4
              && request.resource.data.e == 5;
allow update: if !('d' in request.resource.data)
              && !('e' in request.resource.data);
```

**Result:**

Document **Creation**: Permission **Granted**

Document **Updation**: Permission **Denied**

**Here is my Android code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText txtObjectId;
    Button btnCreate, btnUpdate;
    FirebaseFirestore db;
    private String objectId;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(MainActivity.this);

        btnCreate = findViewById(R.id.btnCreate);
        btnUpdate = findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);
        txtObjectId = findViewById(R.id.txtObjectID);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);

        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        btnCreate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                progressDialog.setMessage("Creating Object");
                progressDialog.show();
                objectId = txtObjectId.getText().toString().trim();
                db.collection("Collection").document(objectId).set(new Model(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            progressDialog.hide();
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Document Created Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                        }
                        else{
                            progressDialog.hide();
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Document Creation Unsucessful: " + task.getException(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                progressDialog.setMessage("Updating Object");
                progressDialog.show();
                objectId = txtObjectId.getText().toString().trim();
                //HERE I AM ONLY UPDATING THE FIELDS A and B, BUT STILL THE SECURITY RULES DENY THE PERMISSION
                //EVEN THOUGH THE SECURITY RULES CHECK IF THE UPDATE CONTAINS THE FIELDS D and E
                db.collection("Collection").document(objectId).update("a", -5, "b", -10).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            progressDialog.hide();
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Document Updated Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        else{
                            progressDialog.hide();
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Document Update Unsucessful: " + task.getException(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

Comment: this does not seem to be a question ...

Comment: Yeah, I have updated it.